# Setup And Deployment in .NET with MYSQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, setup-deployment

i have made an window based application in C# and MySQL is my database.now while making setup of application. does it require to install MYSQL @ client's machine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to know is if your application is a client-server application, or just a client application.

1) **Client - Server application**: All clients connect to one central database machine. There you will have to install MySQL.

2) **Client application**: Every installation of the client requires an installation of MySQL.

You will need to deploy the necessary .dll's of MySQL though, which is ( for as far as I can remember ) just one ( mysql.dll ).

If you're building a setup using *Visual Studio*, the needed .ddl's will be compiled in the setup for you.

Hope this gives you the information you need..